# UIViewController intercept copy/paste actions of UITextView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uitextview, uipasteboard

I have a UITextView inside a UIViewController. I want to intercept (or override) cut/copy/paste and other UIEdit actions in UITextView in my UIViewController. I tried the following code in my UIViewController subclass but it doesn't seems to invoke my custom copy/paste functions.

```
  override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
  }

  override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
      NSLog("Copy called")
  }

   override func paste(_ sender: Any?) {
       NSLog("Paste called")
   }
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and what needs to be done to invoke the above copy/paste functions?

Answer (score 1):

So, here your responder chain is not proper to handle the `copy`, `paste` and other

In-oder to achieve your requirement you can create a custom `textView` class and add that to your `view` of `ViewController`

```
class UserEventsTextView: UITextView {

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
      return true
    }

    override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
        NSLog("Copy called")
    }

     override func paste(_ sender: Any?) {
         NSLog("Paste called")
     }

}
```

Comment: What about super calls?

Comment: It is up to you, if you call `super` default swizzling actions can be performed by default. If you doesn't call then it will avoids the default responder chain